# How can I add the Schema.org type 'BreadcrumbList'?

Tags: breadcrumbs, 7

I want to add the Schema.org type `BreadcrumbList` for my website.

I have installed [Schema.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/schemaorg) module, but I'm unable to find any option there.

I tried using the [Easy Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) module, but it does not have the Schema.org type `BreadcrumbList`.

I have checked on the [Schema.org](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) website and there in example given for JSON-LD.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourtheme_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $sep = ' &gt; ';
  if (count($variables['breadcrumb']) > 0) {
    return implode($sep, $variables['breadcrumb']);
  }
  else {
    return t("Home");
  }
}
```

Comment: follow this link http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/tutorial-how-work-and-style-breadcrumbs-drupal-7

Comment: this is vary good  example

Comment: I don't understand how does this solve the question - can you elaborate please?

Comment: Thanks Raj, but this is not what I am looking for... :)

Answer (score 0):

Schema.org module does not seem to support this.

What you would need is the [Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) module with [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/path_breadcrumbs-schema_org-support-2476089_5.patch). It is supposed to provide Schema.org breadcrumb integration. Bear in mind that the patch is not yet committed, and it's still in reviewing process.

You can see the discussion [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2476089).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aram, I will definitely try this solution and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Aram, I tried with your solution yesterday. Its giving me the breadcrumbs for each page but breadcrumb schema is appied only for first page. Its not appling for remaining pages. Ex. I am having three links on Home page, so schema breadcrumb is getting applied only for first link.

Comment: You will have to keep that issue updated if it didn't work for you; maintainers of that module are still working on that and your feedback will help them.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Crumbs

https://drupal.org/project/crumbs, since 7.x-2.7, automatically adds a JSON-LD BreadcrumbList to the page.

Note that

- Google takes some time to pick up the changes.
- Sometimes Google rejects the breadcrumb on a page for unexplained reasons.

If you used easy breadcrumb before, you could configure Crumbs to be 100% equivalent with it. But probably it won't be necessary.

### Using Easy Breadcrumbs

If you want to continue using Easy Breadcrumbs, you can do it yourself with e.g. hook_html_head_alter(). Some code inspiration:
https://cgit.drupalcode.org/crumbs/tree/lib/CurrentPageInfo.php#n340
https://cgit.drupalcode.org/crumbs/tree/lib/CurrentPageInfo.php#n382
https://cgit.drupalcode.org/crumbs/tree/crumbs.module#n59

Since you won't have the same data available as with Crumbs, you might want to use drupal_get_breadcrumb() as a starting point.

Of course you could also post a feature request with Easy Breadcrumbs.

### Why JSON-LD?

See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115107/seo-schema-org-breadcrumb-with-display-none

The goal was to have structured data that does not conflict with the themed html of the visible breadcrumb.

### Why the html head?

I think the JSON-LD can be anywhere in the page, it does not have to be in the head. The head just seemed a suitable place.